# Leave letter from employer for visa - UK and Schengen, separate letters or one?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, international-travel

I am travelling to Poland for 3 days and UK for 8 days in June, and then to Germany in August for about 6 days. These are two separate trips. I am getting a leave/NOC letter from my employer for this purpose. I have 2 questions:

1. Do I need separate letters for all these leave periods and visa types?
2. Do I need separate letters for UK and Schengen?

Or one letter with all the dates mentioned are fine?

This is my first international trip so I am figuring out stuff.

Answer (score 5):

If the embassies require the original documents, then two documents are needed, as you might be submitting those simultaneously.

Comment: One letter per application, given that originals are typically required

Comment: @Traveller You again! Thanks man, I am getting two, one for UK and the other for Schengen. Will that suffice?